# Possible to extract bitmap data from an flv stream?

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming, flv

Hi Sounds like it might be impossible, but was wondering if it was possible to extract bitmap data from an flv stream?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?  An FLV stream would have a TON of data when converted to Bitmaps, and I doubt you want to capture every frame... but maybe you do.  If you are only interested in capturing a frame or two, then you could certainly do that.  If you really do want to convert the entire FLV to Bitmaps (or any raster format for that matter) then using something like ffmpeg or avisynth will be a much better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, if you have the file on your server you can use ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:10 -t 1 -s 400x300 -i <VideoFile> -f mjpeg <imgFile>
```

-ss is time position the for the ScreenShot

but if that is a youtube video you may use ;
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/[videoCode]/default.jpg
Like;

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YXkwQzJHb6s/default.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YXkwQzJHb6s/0.jpg (big one)
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YXkwQzJHb6s/1.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YXkwQzJHb6s/2.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YXkwQzJHb6s/3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

could try using the hypeframework screencapture, not sure if it will work with video though. Still worth a try I guess

http://blog.six4rty.ch/2010/07/11/as3-take-a-screenshot-of-displayobject/

and

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design/quick-tip-how-to-export-flash-to-png-with-hype/